# SQL server if verify backup integrity fails do something

Tags: sql-server-2012

I have made a sql server agent backup job with 'Verify Backup Integrity' checked. I want to call the job from within a stored procedure using sp_start_job. Then if the backup integrity fails I want to do something (rollback/show error message..something like that). How will i go about doing this? Will sp_start_job return an error or return 1 or what?

Answer (score 0):

I figured out that the job does not return 1, because the job takes time to complete and get to the job failed part. Found this useful link to wait for job to finish then you can catch the error.

http://www.interworks.com/blogs/bbickell/2010/01/15/how-execute-and-monitor-agent-job-using-t-sql-sql-server-20052008